# Difficulty Displaying Retrieved Data from API in Flask Templates

Tags: python, html, json, flask, httprequest

I've been facing an issue with my Flask application where I'm attempting to display data retrieved from an API in my HTML templates but have run into some difficulties. Here's a brief overview of my setup:

**File: search_Page.py (Test script)**

```
import requests

url = 'https://narutodb.xyz/api/character'
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json()['characters'][0])  # This displays the fetched response successfully
else:
    print('Error:', response.status_code)
```

**File: routes.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request, render_template
import requests

naruto_bp = Blueprint('naruto', __name__)

# Other routes...

@naruto_bp.route('/character')
def show_all_characters():
    api_url = 'https://narutodb.xyz/api/'
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        characters_data = response.json()['characters']
        return render_template('character_list.html', characters_data=characters_data)
    else:
        return 'Error retrieving data.'
```

**File: character_list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Character List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>List of Characters</h1>
    <ul>
        <!-- I'm trying to display character names here -->
        {% for character in characters_data %}
            <li>
                <p>{{ character['name'] }}</p>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Despite successfully retrieving the data in the search_Page.py file (solely for testing purposes), I've been encountering issues displaying this data in my Flask templates (character_list.html). The code runs without errors, but the data doesn't seem to render in the HTML. Could someone please review my code and provide insights or potential solutions to this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!

As I said, I tested this whole thing in my seperate testing file and there I managed to get this output:
`{ "characters": [{ "id": 0, "name": "Zero-Tails", "images": ["https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/8/87/Zero_tails.png"], "debut": { "novel": "Naruto Shippūden the Movie: Bonds", "movie": "Naruto Shippūden the Movie: Bonds", "appearsIn": "Novel, Movie" }, "jutsu": ["Shadow Arms"], "personal": { "species": "Leech" }, "uniqueTraits": ["Detects negative emotions", "Feeds on darkness in a beings heart to create dark chakra"] }, { "id": 1, "name": "Ten-Tails", "images": ["https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/e/e6/Ten-Tails_emerges.png"], "debut": { "manga": "Naruto Chapter #467", "anime": "Naruto Shippūden Episode #205", "novel": "The Last: Naruto the Movie", "movie": "The Last: Naruto the Movie", "game": "Naruto Shippūden: Ultimate Ninja Storm Revolution", "ova": "The Far Reaches of Hope", "appearsIn": "Anime, Manga, Novel, Game, Movie" }, "family": { "incarnation with the god tree": "Kaguya Ōtsutsuki", "depowered form": "Demonic Statue of the Outer Path" }, "jutsu": ["Six Paths Senjutsu", "Tailed Beast Ball", "Tailed Beast Chakra Arms", "Tailed Beast Shockwave", "Ten-Tails Fission", "Tenpenchii", "Truth-Seeking Ball", "Wood Release: Cutting Technique"], "natureType": ["Fire Release", "Wind Release", "Lightning Release", "Earth Release", "Water Release", "Wood Release", "Yin Release", "Yang Release", "Yin–Yang Release"], "personal": { "status": "Incapacitated", "kekkeiGenkai": "Wood Release", "classification": "Tailed Beast", "jinchūriki": ["Hagoromo Ōtsutsuki", "Obito Uchiha", "Madara Uchiha"], "titles": ["十尾Jūbi", "one-eyedGod(天目一箇神,AmeNoHitotsuNoKami)", "datara(ダタラ)", "deidarabotchi(デイダラボッチ,Deidarabocchi)", "nation-buildingGod(国造りの神,KunizukuriNoKami)"] }, "uniqueTraits": ["Can absorb chakra"] }, { "id": 2, "name": "Three-Headed Guardian Beast", "images": ["https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/7/79/Three-Heads_after_release.png"], "personal": { "affiliation": "Yumegakure" } }`